# Quarkus pom file with two errors from Getting started project

Tags: java, spring, maven, build, quarkus

Today I started looking at Quarkus and following the Getting Started project.
After created the project using maven:

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.9.2.Final:create \
-DprojectGroupId=org.acme \
-DprojectArtifactId=getting-started \
-DclassName="org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResource" \
-Dpath="/hello"
```

and import into Eclipse, I'm having two errors as:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.9.2.Final:generate-code (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)    pom.xml /getting-started    line 57 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

The error is pointing to the build section of the pom file and the tag execution is highlighted as red:

> 

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
<artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>generate-code</goal>
<goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
<goal>build</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
<configuration>
<systemPropertyVariables>
<java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
<maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
</systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I tried to include the 'pluginManagement' between the plugins tag as below and the error disappeared:

> 

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
<artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>generate-code</goal>
<goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
<goal>build</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
<configuration>
<systemPropertyVariables>
<java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
<maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
</systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

but when running the app as:

> ./mvnw compile quarkus:dev

It's not running. I had to remove the PluginManagement and everything back to work but with the same error in red

Comment: Have you tried to check your maven version? Bootstraping a Quarkus application from command line only works for Maven > 3.6.X.

Answer (score 0):

in my case that issue appeared because the port 8080 was busy with another server. When I had chaneged the used port to another one, then Quarqus succesfuly launched to the 8080.

Comment: I did `server.port` on `application.properties` and keeping the tag `pluginManagement` but when starting quarkus as `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev`, It's displaying a warning as  `[WARNING] The quarkus-maven-plugin build goal was not configured for this project, skipping quarkus:dev as this is assumed to be a support library. If you want to run quarkus dev on this project make sure the quarkus-maven-plugin is configured with a build goal.`